# Complex Analysis 246A

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I am about to take a *complex analysis* course (**Math 246A**) by **Terence Tao**. I have the knowledge of pre-calculus and have picked up first year's calculus (from Thomas' Calculus, about to finish it). So as I am a grade 11th student, can you recommend me any resources for learning/preparing for complex analysis? Since I don't know much about complex analysis I don't know where to look for the resources. Also let me know anything else that I have to read.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you are genuinely signed up for the course, why not ask the instructor himself for advice?

Comment: @KCd I am not an UCLA student, but Terry has made the course open accec (for lectures only) but not resources for enrolled students. Also he lists only Stein and Shakarachi's Text which I have downloaded but I wanted some other books or notes that could supplement it as I won't have course materials. Though Terry's blog does have some notes, I want some other notes for prerequisites. Any lecture notes would also help..

Comment: I quote from https://terrytao.wordpress.com/category/teaching/246a-complex-analysis/: Math 246 is "the first course in the three-quarter graduate complex analysis sequence".  That settles it. Sorry, but based on your described background you need a reality check: you are *totally unprepared* to take a graduate-level math course soon when all you know is Thomas' Calculus.  Graduate students are assumed to have already learned multivariable calculus, linear algebra, and at least a semester of real analysis (epsilon-delta arguments, uniform continuity, compactness, connectedness, etc.)

Comment: Watch the video lectures if you want, but be prepared to be lost pretty quickly.  Your time would be much better spent trying to learn some real analysis that builds off what you have learned in calculus.

Answer (score 0):

A standard class in complex variables may cover: Complex numbers, the complex plane. Power series, differentiability of convergent power series. Cauchy-Riemann equations, harmonic functions. conformal mapping, linear fractional transformation. Integration, Cauchy integral theorem, Cauchy integral formula. Morera's theorem. Taylor series, residue calculus. Maximum modulus theorem. Poisson formula. Liouville theorem. Rouche's theorem. Weierstrass and Mittag-Leffler representation theorems. Singularities of analytic functions, poles, branch points, essential singularities, branch points. Analytic continuation, monodromy theorem, Schwarz reflection principle. Compactness of families of uniformly bounded analytic functions. Integral representations of special functions. Distribution of function values of entire functions.

For advanced topics, it really varies from class to class.

**Here are some sources I recommend when I studied complex variables:**

Brown and Churchill's Complex Analysis, 8th edition; This is a friendly introduction to beginners in complex analysis, involving most of the calculations and concrete examples. But in my opinion, this book is not rigorous enough for proofs.

Marsden and Hoffman's Basic Complex Analysis, 3rd edition: This is an advanced undergraduate text in complex analysis, in my opinion. More rigorous proofs are involved, but also it provides practice examples with solutions. Personally I recommend this book if you have used to do proofs.

**Here are some more advanced texts:**

Lars Ahlfor's Complex Analysis, 3rd edition: This is a standard textbook for graduate level complex analysis. It explains complex analysis intuitively in a way of geometric point. But this book is somehow outdated, and some exercises are hard and take time to solve them. You can find relevant solutions online.

Serge Lang's Complex Analysis, 4th edition:

Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis:

Greene and Krantz's Function Theory of One Complex Variable, 3rd edition: I referenced this book before, written in a compact and dense sense. There are many exercises in this book. I used to practice them when I was learning the material.

Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition: I don't recommend this, since this book only gives sketches of proofs.

Hope you succeed in the complex analysis class!

Comment: That's really an exhaustive and great answer. I will sure use them. Thanks for taking time to answer my question...